# Formula that displays data if the word ends with particular string

Tags: crystal-reports

I need a formula that, if the `ItemDescription` contains the words "Black Feet", displays "romano chair" without the word "Feet".

My current formula is:

```
if WorkOrder.ConfigProptext} like "*Feet*" then
```

How can I do this in Crystal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace every instance of "Black Feet", use:

```
REPLACE({Table.ItemDescription}, "Black Feet", "Romano Chair")
```

If you want a condition returns true if the description contains "Feet", use:

```
INSTR({Table.ItemDescription}, "Feet") > 0
```